# Passing a DataFrame into a function in R? Getting NULL when I try to return a column from it

Tags: r

```
get_column <- function(df, feature) {
      return(df$feature)
}

get_column(mtcars, "mpg")
## NULL
```

When I put a dataframe into an argument of the above function and try to return a column from it. I get NULL as the result. Why is this the case and how can I properly perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `[[` instead of `$`. Also, `return` wrapping is not really needed in `R`.  According to `?return`

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.

```
get_column <- function(df, feature) {
     return(df[[feature]])
   }
```

Comment: Why does the `$` not work here? And how does it know what to return without a return wrapping?

Comment: @Elsen Updated the post.  With the `$`, it is doing  a literal evaluation for 'feature' instead of the value passed with feature.  So, it i looking for `df$feature` of `df$mpg`